# Rails 3: undefined method `remote_form_for'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, haml, rails-3-upgrade

I have a fairly simple Rails remote form in HAML in a partial under shared/users:

```
- remote_form_for :user, :url => { :controller => "users", :action => "create" } do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :name, t('name')
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.label :email, t('email')
    = f.text_field :email
  .actions
    = f.submit
```

No matter how much I fiddle with it, this just won't work. I alway get the following error:

```
undefined method `remote_form_for' for #<#<Class:0x1036e8e40>:0x1036dfd90>
```

Am I doing something stupid? It works perfectly with form_for.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

remote_form_for no longer exists.

Try adding

```
:remote => true
```

as an option to form_for

```
form_for :user, :remote => true, :url => { :controller => "users", :action => "create" } do |f|
```

see:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Answer (score 1):

It's because this method is delete on Rails 3

Use now

```
form_for ..., :remote => true
```

Your code becomes :

```
- form_for :user, :url => { :controller => "users", :action => "create" }, :remote => true do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :name, t('name')
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.label :email, t('email')
    = f.text_field :email
  .actions
    = f.submit
```

And you need the rails.jquery.js or same in prototype to use it. It's the UJS improvement in rails.