# How to make the page not redirect in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an erb file named index that has a form in it. As a simple example:

```
<% form_for @foo, :url => {:action => 'bar'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "BAR!" %>
<%end%>
```

When I click the BAR! button it preforms the actions I expect and it forwards me onto the bar.erb file, displaying the expected output. What I would like to be able to do, however, is to take the generated html from this page and stuff it into the innerHTML of a div on the index page. I assume there is a way but I must ask, is there a way to achieve this? Are there any examples available that would be helpful? Thanks!

Comment: seems to be a good work for an ajax call ... easy way is to use a remote_form_for , than in your controller you could use prototype_helper to perform a replace html in the ajax response. you have to google prototypehelper(or jruby if you prefer jquery) remote_form_for , rjs .

Comment: Just remember that `remote_form_for` isn't in Rails 3. It was replaced by a cleaner solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890315/rails-3-undefined-method-remote-form-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass the id of the div to update like so:

```
<% remote_form_for @foo, :url => {:action => 'bar'}, :update => 'id-of-div-to-update' do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "BAR!" %>
<%end%>
```

In the controller:

```
def bar
  # your code here
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(xxx) }
      format.js   
    end
end
```

Rails will look for a template named bar.js and will render it and return it's content to the browser without a redirect.

Comment: This still seems to redirect the page. Is all you have to do is to add the update value or is there more to it than that?

Comment: I edited my answer to include an example of handling the js request.